# Replacing strings with replace_all that have a specific beginning

Tags: r, regex, str-replace

I have a data set with open answers and I'm working with R. What I want to do is to summarize different answers with the same meaning that are sometimes spelled differently etc.

For example, there are these two open answers: "Anwalt", "Anwältin" and "Dozent/Anwalt".
For each answers that involves the word stem "Anw", I want R to replace it with "Anwalt/Anwältin".

For "Anwalt" and "Anwältin", I tried this command:

`offene_antworten$vb_wunsch <- str_replace_all(offene_antworten$vb_wunsch, c("(^Anw)" = "Anwalt/Anwältin"))`

But it resolves in: Anwalt/Anwältinältin and I still have to solution for "Dozent/Anwalt". I tried variations of the str_replace_all function, regular expressions and read several blogs but I can't find a solution.

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you want `str_replace_all(offene_antworten$vb_wunsch, c("\\bAnw\\w*" = "Anwalt/Anwältin"))`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to replace every answer that contains `"Anw"` with `"Anwalt/Anwältin"`, if so you can:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Consider this sample

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   question answer       
      <int> <chr>        
 1        1 Anwältin     
 2        2 Anwalt       
 3        3 Anwältin     
 4        4 Chocolate    
 5        5 Chocolate    
 6        6 Dozent/Anwalt
 7        7 Chocolate    
 8        8 Dozent/Anwalt
 9        9 Anwältin     
10       10 Anwalt       

df %>%  
  mutate(answer = case_when(str_detect(str_to_lower(answer), 
                                       "anw") ~ "Anwalt/Anwältin", 
                            TRUE ~ answer))

    # A tibble: 10 x 2
       question answer         
          <int> <chr>          
     1        1 Anwalt/Anwältin
     2        2 Anwalt/Anwältin
     3        3 Anwalt/Anwältin
     4        4 Chocolate      
     5        5 Chocolate      
     6        6 Anwalt/Anwältin
     7        7 Chocolate      
     8        8 Anwalt/Anwältin
     9        9 Anwalt/Anwältin
    10       10 Anwalt/Anwältin
```

Comment: Thank you! The thing is that in this example, I only want to replace everything that starts with "Anw" and when I have "Dozent/Anwalt", I want to keep the word Dozent but replace Anwalt.

I used this code now: 

`offene_antworten$vb_wunsch <- str_replace(offene_antworten$vb_wunsch, "Anw", "Anwalt/Anwältin")`

But it still only replaces "Anw" and not the whole word that starts with "Anw".

The whole idea is that I don't want to spell out the word "Anwalt" to change it but to say, change everything that starts with "Anw", just to safe time and code.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Considering upper or lower case
char <- c("Anwalt", "Anwältin", "Dozent/Anwalt", "anw", "wAn", "abcd")
char[grepl("Anw", char)] <- "Anwalt/Anwältin"

> char
[1] "Anwalt/Anwältin" "Anwalt/Anwältin" "Anwalt/Anwältin" "anw"            
[5] "wAn"             "abcd"  


# Without considering upper or lower case
char2 <- char
char2[grepl("anw", tolower(char2))] <- "Anwalt/Anwältin"

> char2
[1] "Anwalt/Anwältin" "Anwalt/Anwältin" "Anwalt/Anwältin" "Anwalt/Anwältin"
[5] "wAn"             "abcd"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char <- c("Dozent/Anwalt", "Anwältin", "abc.asd", 
          "Anwalt", "Dozent\\Anwalt", "ANw/Doz", 
          "doz,anw", "Dozent\asd", "qqq sss")

symbol <- c("/", "-", "[.]", "[,]", " ", "[\\]", "[\\\\]")    # Symbols that may involve

# Detect if there is a symbol within the string and return it
# Note that this could not handle multiple symbols within string
detect_symbols <- function(character, .symbol = symbol){
    for (s in .symbol){
        if (grepl(x = character, pattern = s)){
            return(s)
        }else{next}
    }
}

char2 <- c()
for(c in char){
    if(!is.null(detect_symbols(c))){
        str_vct <- strsplit(c, detect_symbols(c))[[1]]
        str_vct[grepl("anw", tolower(str_vct))] <- "Anwalt/Anwältin"  # string convert
        str_vct <- paste(str_vct, collapse = detect_symbols(c))
        str_vct <- gsub("\\[", "", str_vct)
        str_vct <- gsub("\\]", "", str_vct)
        char2 <- c(char2, str_vct)
    }else{
        c[grepl("anw", tolower(c))] <- "Anwalt/Anwältin"   # string convert
        char2 <- c(char2, c)
    }
}

> char2
[1] "Dozent/Anwalt/Anwältin"  "Anwalt/Anwältin"         "abc.asd"                
[4] "Anwalt/Anwältin"         "Dozent\\Anwalt/Anwältin" "Anwalt/Anwältin/Doz"    
[7] "doz,Anwalt/Anwältin"     "Dozent\asd"              "qqq sss"


# -------------------- Update ------------------------#

# Please have a look on the comments below your post.
# @Wiktor Stribiżew gives out good answer.

library(tidyverse)

char <- c("Dozent/Anwalt", "Anwältin", "abc.asd", 
          "*Anwalt*", "Dozent\\Anwalt", "(ANw)Doz", 
          "doz,anw", "Dozent*asd", "qqq sss", "anw()")

str_replace_all(string = str_to_lower(char), 
                pattern = "\\w*anw\\w*",
                replacement  = "Anwalt/Anwältin")

 [1] "dozent/Anwalt/Anwältin"  "Anwalt/Anwältin"         "abc.asd"                
 [4] "*Anwalt/Anwältin*"       "dozent\\Anwalt/Anwältin" "(Anwalt/Anwältin)doz"   
 [7] "doz,Anwalt/Anwältin"     "dozent*asd"              "qqq sss"                
[10] "Anwalt/Anwältin()"
```

Comment: Thank you @AlpacaKing! This goes in the direction that I want. But the column of my data frame, where I want to change the strings, is missing totally after running the code.
Char2 in my case is "offene_antworten$vb_wunsch". That's the column I need to address. The symbols are "/", "*", "(" and ")". Also I haven't worked with the for () function before and I'm a beginner to R. Thank you for your help!